# How to know the end of arbitrary number of asynchronous operations

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, cocoa

I need to perform some network calls. I am using NSURLConnection but I've encapsulated that into a new class that uses blocks:

```
    [MAURLConnection asyncConnectionWithURLString:str 
                                  completionBlock:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response) {
                                      //completed, do something with data returned

                                  } 
                                       errorBlock:^(NSError *error) {
                                           //error
                                       }];
}
```

But, now I need to call several of these at once, but I need to know when they all finish. What's the best way to do this? I don't necessarily need the progress, just when they all have finished.

Comment: Whenever a job starts, increment a counter. When each job finishes, decrement the counter. When the counter is 0, you're done.

Comment: @Almo This implies that you can increment and decrement atomically, which is not true unless you use locking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest think I can think of is a counter. When each connection finishes just increase a counter. Once counter has reached your number you're done. You can also increase counter thru some function and run notification when counter number is hit.
Variation of this might be array where you could also store some additional info about finished connection.

Answer (score 0):

Another variation on Almo's comment is to push them into a queue-like structure and upon completion the length of the queue will be zero. To accomplish a non-blocking check to see if the queue is empty, use a run-loop.

```
- (void)waitUntilDone {       
    while (![_queue count] > 0) {
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
    }
}
```

Depending on your needs you can use this to block and call you back, place it in a thread and continue doing stuff and call you back.